# Array of object fields

Tags: object, field, julia

How can I get an array with all the fields of an object? Suppose I have an object `obj` with fields `a` and `b`, I want to get an array with all the fields `[:a, :b]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fieldnames(obj)`. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.fieldnames.